# output of pwm/ speed controller with input from voltage stabilizer

Tags: pwm

I am having a voltage stabilizer which is connected to AC and the output of voltage stabilizer is connected as input to a pwm for controlling a 12V, 10A dc motor.The doubt i was having is that the output of pwm is showing 17 V when i am not connecting the motor to it and using the potentiometer i could vary the voltage upto 16V but when i am connecting dc motor to output of pwm i was able to vary voltages from nearly 2-15V. will the output of pwm vary depending on the instrument which we have connected to it or I am thinking in a wrong way

Answer (score 1):

Without load, a PWM speed controller will typically read higher voltage due to parasitic capacitances in the circuit. Here is a simplified schematic of a unidirectional PWM motor speed control:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKo0G0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 and C2 represent the parasitic capacitances inside D1 and M1.

In operation, M1 acts as a switch which connects Motor- to ground when turned ON (PWM high), and is open circuit when OFF (PWM low). When M1 is ON the parasitic capacitance is rapidly charged to the supply voltage. However when M1 is OFF the parasitic capacitance can only discharge through the meter, which it does slowly due to the high meter resistance. This 'fills in the gaps' between PWM ON periods and causes the average voltage to be higher than expected.

As well as parasitic capacitance the FET will also have some leakage, which may cause the meter to read some voltage even at 0% PWM.

When you attach a load with much lower resistance (eg. a motor or light bulb) the parasitic capacitance can discharge rapidly and leakage current produces very little voltage across the load, so the average voltage is closer to what you would expect.

Also since the motor is drawing relatively high current your power supply may be putting out a lower voltage. A '12V' unregulated power supply typically produces as much as 17V when unloaded because the peak voltage of rectified AC is 1.4 times the rms voltage. As current draw approaches the power supply's rated value the voltage drops due to losses in the transformer, rectifier diodes and filter capacitor. This may explain why you see up to 17V unloaded, but only 15V with the motor connected.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation sir. I am having one more doubt whether can I use the above mentioned power supply(voltage stabilizer) for running the 12 v dc motor using the pwm.

Comment: What do you doubt about it?